# Why am I receiving an "Access Not Configured" error?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I tried my request to the `youtube-data-API-v3` on Google Explorer and everything worked fine (including my API key). When I try to simply put the URL request in the browser, OR I try it in my AJAX code, I get the same error returned (below).

My API is enabled, and it says I can have 3,000,000 hits per day.

Why does it say "Access Not Configured" when I set it up on the Google developer site and it says ENABLED? Is that the problem? How do I fix that?

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key={MY_API_KEY}&q=test&maxResults=4

Actual response:

> ..."message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been
>   used in project 916159313635 before or it is disabled. Enable it by
>   visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=916159313635
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

Comment: You **did** see the *If you enabled this API recently, **wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.*** A few minutes might mean an hour or two. If it doesn't start working then, contact Google directly for help with your account - we have no access to it and no way to see what's wrong with your specific account.

Comment: Yes sir, I actually waited a day and a half. Thank you, though.

Comment: Well, I guess fixed the problem with a 'reboot' of sorts:I went back into Google developer, deleted my project and keys, created a whole new project, new key, and it decided to work. A quirk within Google, I guess.  Thank you to anyone who gave it some time; appreciate it.

Comment: Had the exact same issue with the Youtube Data API v3, I've been using the same auth key for a year and suddenly stopped working with the same error message. Enabling/Disabling the API, deleting keys or generating new keys had *zero* effect. Ended up having to create an entirely new project. Definitely seems like something on their end.